# How to split different type of string in a List

Tags: java

I have a list which contains list of values like below

```
[a-xyz,b-yzx,c-aaa,d-rrr,a-qqq,b-hhh]
```

and i need the above list like below

```
[xyz,yzx,aaa,rrr,qqq,hhh]
```

Comment: what is your problem? what have you tried and what did not work for you ?

Comment: `String#split` is what you are looking for

Comment: yes ,i am looking for split

Comment: Your input is not valid Java. Are you reading form a String like `String s = "[a-xyz,b-yzx,c-aaa,d-rrr,a-qqq,b-hhh]"`?

Comment: @LutzHorn OP obviously has a `List<String>` with the posted Strings in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a-xyz","b-yzx","c-aaa","d-rrr","a-qqq","b-hhh");
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .map(s -> s.replaceFirst("^.*-", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

result:

```
[xyz, yzx, aaa, rrr, qqq, hhh]
```

Or Java7

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a-xyz","b-yzx","c-aaa","d-rrr","a-qqq","b-hhh");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list)
    result.add(s.replaceFirst("^.*-", ""));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: could you please simplify the code , i am using jdk 1.7

Answer (score 1):

There a several things that should be done here. First, you need to get rid of the enclosing `[]` so the string could be split. Then, you need to actually split it (by commas). Then, for each string, you need to remove the  prefix before the `-`. Java 8's stream give you a pretty neat way of doing this:

```
List<String> result =
    Arrays.stream(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(","))
          .map(s -> s.replaceFirst("\\w-", ""))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:
In JDK 7 and below the solution would be similar, but you'd have to resort to using loops instead of streams:

```
String[] arr = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(",");
List<Stirng> result = new ArrayList<>(arr.length);
for (String s : arr) {
    result.add(s.replaceFirst("\\w-", ""));
}
```

Comment: i am using jdk 1.7 ,could you please simplify the code

Comment: @chandrasekhar The idea is similar, although you'd have to use loops instead of streams. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

call me old-fashioned

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Split {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ss = {"a-xyz","b-yzx","c-aaa","d-rrr","a-qqq","b-hhh"};
        List<String> ll = new ArrayList<>();
        ll.addAll(Arrays.asList(ss));

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s:ll) {
            result.add(s.split("-")[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

gives

```
[xyz, yzx, aaa, rrr, qqq, hhh]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same list to store final value using set method of list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SplitList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("a-xyz");
        list.add("b-yzx");
        list.add("c-aaa");
        list.add("d-rrr");
        list.add("a-qqq");
        list.add("b-hhh");
        for(String st : list){
            int index = list.indexOf(st); //get index of string
            list.set(index,st.replaceFirst("\\w-", "")); //set only with required value
        }
        for(String st : list){
            System.out.println(st);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException could occure in`st.split("-")[1]` in case of rough data. It's better to use replace with regexp or `Pattern - Matcher`.